# Can I have more than four non-basic lands with the same name in my deck?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

Am I allowed to have 5 [Bottomless Vault](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bBottomless%20Vault%5d)s in my deck?

Answer (score 1):

No, the maximum allowed number of copies for each card is four. The only exceptions are basic lands ([Forest](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=461189), [Snow-covered Forest](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bSnow-covered%20Forest%5d)) and cards which specifically mention they're exceptions (like [Relentless Rats](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bRelentless%20Rats%5d)).

> 100.2a In constructed play (a way of playing in which each player creates their own deck ahead of time), each deck must contain at least sixty cards. A constructed deck may contain any number of basic land cards and no more than four of any card with a particular English name other than basic land cards.

(from the [Comprehensive Rules](https://media.wizards.com/2019/downloads/MagicCompRules%2020190125.txt))

So in the rare case that you're playing a Fifth Edition draft (that's a Limited format) and manage to draft five Bottomless Vaults, then it would be allowed.